# Password checking RegEx that matches multiple criteria

Tags: .net, regex, visual-studio

After searching extensively on Google and SO I ran into an issue. I am trying to write a regex based off one I found on SO

1. The string must be 8-24 characters, and
2. The string needs to match two of the following criteria (minimally), in addition to the length:

   - Upper Case
   - Lower Case
   - Numeric
   - Non-AlphaNumeric

This is the regex I have been trying to modify:

```
^.*(?=.{8,24})(?=.*\d|\W)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$
```

I need to modify this is to ensure a password matches the criteria above.

I cannot go in and programmatically do this because it would change other fundamentals of how some of our code works. Right now we have the regex check in place so all I must do is update a config file with the new expression.

Comment: May I ask how doing is problematically would change other fundamentals?   Regex was not really built for 2/4 conditions logic.

Comment: Overly restrictive password policies can easily backfire on you: (eg: people will just write them down on a sticky note next to their computers, or will forget them, bringing frustration to them and problems to you).

Comment: To change the code i would have to update many of our servers. To use regex i change one setting and its propagated immediately

Comment: To answer the question itself; yes, you can modify the regex but it will be ugly. You'd be much better off changing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not pretty, but you *can* efficiently do it with a single regex using brute force like so (assuming C#):

### Regex to match 2 of 4 passwords criteria:

```cs
Regex re = new Regex(@"
    # Match 2 of 4 passwords criteria and length from 8 to 24.
    ^                   # Anchor to start of string.
    (?:                 # Group acceptable pair alternatives.
      (?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])  # At least one Upper Case.
      (?=[^a-z]*[a-z])  # At least one Lower Case.
    |                   # or...
      (?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])  # At least one Upper Case.
      (?=[^0-9]*[0-9])  # At least one Numeric.
    |                   # or...
      (?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])  # At least one Upper Case.
      (?=\w*\W)         # At least one Non-AlphaNumeric.
    |                   # or...
      (?=[^a-z]*[a-z])  # At least one Lower Case.
      (?=[^0-9]*[0-9])  # At least one Numeric.
    |                   # or...
      (?=[^a-z]*[a-z])  # At least one Lower Case.
      (?=\w*\W)         # At least one Non-AlphaNumeric.
    |                   # or...
      (?=[^0-9]*[0-9])  # At least one Numeric.
      (?=\w*\W)         # At least one Non-AlphaNumeric.
    )                   # Brute force!
    .{8,24}             # Match from 8 to 24 chars.
    \z                  # Anchor to end of string.
    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
if (re.IsMatch(text)) {
    // Password is valid.
} else {
    // Password is NOT valid.
}
```

There are six possible combinations of the 2 out of 4 requirements. The final `.{8,24}` length check assumes that any char other than a newline is ok (you may/should want to modify this).

**Edit:** I see now that dbaupp's answer works just fine (I gave it my upvote). Although my expression to find an uppercase letter: `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` is more efficient than: `(?=.*[A-Z])` (and the same goes for the other lookaheads). On the other hand, dbaupp's answer is more efficient with regard to the grouping.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try something like (remove whitespace)

```
^
(((?=.*[a-z])
  ((?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W))) |
 ((?=.*[A-Z])
  ((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W))) | 
 ((?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)))
.{8,24}
$
```

This is structured like:

```
^<char restrictions><length restriction>$
```

where

```
char restriction = (<lower> and (<upper> or <numeric> or <non-alphanum>)) 
                  or (<upper> and (<numeric> or <non-alphanum>))
                  or (<numeric> and <non-alphanum>)
```

(All of these are look-aheads.)

The length restriction is not a look-ahead because we need to tell the regex engine that there should be between 8 and 24 characters between the start and end of the string. (By putting `.*` anywhere at the top-level, we lose the ability to do this restriction.)

---

However, one should make every effort to change the code, rather than use this horrible regex.

Comment: The OP is implying that changing the code to allow this change would require a lot of code changes. This tells me the way the code is structured is probably wrong.

Comment: +1 Yup this one will do the trick. But `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` is a bit more efficient than: `(?=.*[A-Z])`.

Comment: It's subtle, but this should end with `\z` instead of `$` or the user could enter up to 25 characters. `"x\n"` matches `"^.$"` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_password_strength(x):
    ## Initialize the toggle flags to check 3 conditions - Capital Letter/Small Letter/Numeric Value
    flag_capital_letter = 0
    flag_small_letter = 0
    flag_numerical_letter = 0
    
    ## Message strings that will be displayed to the user
    strong_pass_msg = "Strong password"
    weak_pass_msg = "Weak Password"
    
    if len(x) >= 6 and len(x) <= 12 : ## Ensure the Length of Password between [6,12], both inclusive 
        if '#' in x or '$' in x or '@' in x : ## At least one Special Character Should be in password
            for i in x:  ## Loop for parsing the string to check for 3 remaining conditions
                if i.islower():
                    flag_small_letter = 1
                if i.isupper():
                    flag_capital_letter = 1
                if i.isnumeric():
                    flag_numerical_letter = 1
            ## if all three conditions are fulfilled, all flags toggle to 1
            if flag_numerical_letter == 1 and flag_capital_letter == 1 and flag_small_letter == 1:
                return(strong_pass_msg)
            else:
                return(weak_pass_msg)
        else:
            return(weak_pass_msg)
    else:
        return(weak_pass_msg)
    
username = input("Enter your Username: ")
password = input("Enter Password: ")
check_password_strength(password)
```